# Trouble to MongoDB Single Node Replica Set in Docker Container

Tags: mongodb, docker, replicaset

I am trying to run MongoDB in a Docker container and apply a Single Node Replica Set in an Oracle Cloud Ubuntu environment without using docker-compose.

When I execute rs.initiate() in mongosh, members are automatically created with the container's ID (/etc/hosts). However, when trying to connect externally using Compass, I get the error message "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND $CONTAINER_ID" and cannot establish a connection.

I have tried changing the host information in rs.initiate() arguments to 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', and external IP, but none of them work. I have also tried changing Docker's ports, but the issue persists.

Currently, only port `27017` is open in the cloud, and it functions properly.

I am seeking assistance in identifying the problem.

Just in case, I'm adding my options (nothing special)

**In Dockerfile**

```
mongod --bind_ip_all --replSet rs --port 27017
```

**Container Execution**

```
docker run -d \
  -p 27017:27017\
  --name $NAME \
  -v $VOLUME_DIR:/data/db \
  $IMAGE_NAME
```

Attempted Replica Set with IP or ID expected to connect, but failed.
I hope to be connected to the Replica Set(single node, primaey only).

Comment: docker connects from host thru 0.0.0.0 by default, have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But I just tried, 'rs.initiate' doesn't apply with the message below.

(No host described in new configuration with {version: 1, term: 0} for replica set rs maps to this node)

Comment: A way to test this is to see if you can connect using 0.0.0.0 locally. If not, I would try port forwarding in the container as described in the answer to this question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111433/iptables-redirect-outside-requests-to-127-0-0-1

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It will take some time because the network knowledge is very insufficient and I can't speak English at all (because I'm Korean), but I'll try reading it step by step by step.

Answer (score 0):

I had limited knowledge about networking, but I managed to resolve the issue and want to share the solution.

My assumption was that the packet movement was as follows:

- [request] External PC → Server PC → Docker (requesting itself via Mongo Replica Set) → Server PC → Docker
- [response] Server PC - External PC

The problem was at the point where:

- Docker (requesting itself via Mongo Replica Set) → Server PC → Docker

Solutions that have been tried and failed:

- $CONTAINER_IP:$MONGODB_PORT
- $PUBLIC_IP:$MONGODB_PORT

However, when I set different external ports and internal ports, it started working.

Here's what I did to resolve it:

1. When running Docker, I set different external ports and internal ports.
2. I configured the host of the replica set as $PUBLIC_IP:$OUTER_PORT. (Note that $CONTAINER_IP:$OUTER_PORT failed)

To be honest, the packet movement path was based on my assumption, and I'm not sure about the exact mechanism that made it work.

Also, accessing docker containers from a server PC over a public IP might result in losses.
(If anyone has more knowledge about this, please share your opinion.)

What do you think? At least, it's working fine now!